Quarkus Microservice with Kogito fails to start: Unsupported MVEL Compilation in Native Image
I'm encountering an issue with my Quarkus microservice that uses Kogito. The application fails to start when running in native mode, and I'm seeing the following error in the logs:
    2024-06-06 07:16:59,136 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus                                                                          
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MVEL compilation is not supported in native image
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.MVELProcessHelper.lambda$static$1(MVELProcessHelper.java:40)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.MVELProcessHelper.compileExpression(MVELProcessHelper.java:57)
at org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.OutputExpressionAssignment.<init>(OutputExpressionAssignment.java:42)
at org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.DataAssociation.buildInterpretedAssignment(DataAssociation.java:56)
at java.base@17.0.11/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
at org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.DataAssociation.<init>(DataAssociation.java:46)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess.process(TicketWorkflowProcess.java:1116)
at org.kie.kogito.process.impl.AbstractProcess.get(AbstractProcess.java:250)
at org.kogito.process.impl.AbstractProcess.activate(AbstractProcess.java:192)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess.<init>(TicketWorkflowProcess.java:23)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:113)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:37)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:21)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess_ClientProxy.arc_contextualInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.epm.ticket.workflow.TicketWorkflowProcess_Observer_Synthetic_1e642942b2e0ecd00ec189c20062bdec9100a46d.notify(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notifyObservers(EventImpl.java:346)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:328)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:82)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.fireLifecycleEvent(ArcRecorder.java:155)
at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:106)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy(Unknown Source)
... 7 more

Here are some details about my setup:

Quarkus version: 3.2.11.Final-redhat-00001
Kogito version: 2.44.0.Alpha
Java version: 17

It seems that MVEL is not supported in native images...
To generate the native image i used the quarkus native container builder
What am I doing wrong?
